# Backbone.js custom collection sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone.js app with marionette plugin. There's a collection which renders with a CompositeView (and ItemViews) and I need to sort it in the following way:

1. User can rearrange rendered ItemViews (using jQuery sortable plugin) and this user preference gets saved in a cookie in a form of array of model IDs
2. On each reload, I want to sort the fetched collection to be in the same order as this aforementioned array of user preference order.

I tried to sort collection.models array manually in the onRender hook and then re-rendering it, but this kind of collection manipulation just "feels wrong" (and causes an endless render loop).

Is there some kind of a more elegant solution to sort a collection to have models in the same order as model IDs defined in some other array?

Comment: Look at http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [Backbone.Collection#comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) method on collection which will access cookie with array of ids and uses it to return 1 or -1.

> comparator functions take two models, and return -1 if the first model should come before the second, 0 if they are of the same rank and 1 if the first model should come after.

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    comparator: function(model_a, model_b) {
        // In real app array comes from cookie
        var order = [5, 2, 1, 4, 3],
            a_index = order.indexOf(model_a.id),
            b_index = order.indexOf(model_b.id);

        if (a_index > b_index) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a_index < b_index) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

});

var my_collection = new MyCollection([
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 }
]);

alert(my_collection.pluck('id'));
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wup7q9e/) with this example

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to map over your "custom" list of ids and return models in the collection with that id:

```
var items = [
  {id: 0, name: '1st', age: 40},
  {id: 1, name: '2nd', age: 50},
  {id: 2, name: '3rd', age: 60}
];

// order stored in cookie or localstorage ^^
var sorted = [2, 1, 0];

// our source collection
var collection = new Backbone.Collection(items);

// this could be implemented as a collection method if necessary
var sortedCollection = _.map(sorted, function (id) {
  return collection.get(id);
});


var sortedIds = sortedCollection.map(function (item) { return item.id })
console.log(sortedIds);
// [2, 1, 0]
```

**[jsbin with an example view](http://jsbin.com/jikuto/edit)**